# Loading SQLite data using AsyncTask , What am I doing wrong?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite, loader

I'm new to android and java, and I'm trying to implement an Asynchronous Loader. But no data is being loaded. Am I missing something conceptually here?

My Activity:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


ListView bookList;
MyCursorAdapter myAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_library);
  //  dloader = new DBLoader(this);
    //dloader.loadInBackground();

   /* blah blah*/

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);

    /* blah blah*/
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_layout_title, null);
    TextView totals = header.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
    totals.setText("Total Books: " + Integer.toString(totalBooks));
    bookList.addHeaderView(header);

    bookList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            /* blah blah*/
            }


        }
    });
    /* blah blah*/
}

 /* blah blah*/

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
   /*CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this, null, null, null, null, null){
        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground(){
            DBHandler db = new DBHandler(getContext());
            return db.getCursor();
        }
   };*/
   DBLoader loader  = new DBLoader(this);
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    myAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this,data,0);
    bookList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    // myAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    //myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    myAdapter.swapCursor(null);

}
}
```

DBLoader:

```
public class DBLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor> {

private Cursor mCursor;
Context context;
public DBLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() {
    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(context);
    Cursor cursor = db.getCursor();
    return cursor;
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(Cursor cursor){
    if(isReset()){
        releaseResources(cursor);
        return;
    }

    Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    mCursor = cursor;

    if(isStarted()){
        super.deliverResult(cursor);
    }

    if(oldCursor!=null && oldCursor!=cursor){
        releaseResources(oldCursor);
    }
}


private void releaseResources(Cursor cursor) {
    cursor.close();
}
}
```

I don't know if I'm missing any important calls here, and most resources on the internet are about content providers(which I don't need). What I simply need is to asynchronously load data from my local SQLite database.

EDIT: My Adapter:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private LayoutInflater cursorInflater;

public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    cursorInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    return cursorInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    Log.d("Cursor :", cursor.getString(1));
    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
    title.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    TextView author = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listAuthor);
    author.setText(cursor.getString(2));
    TextView copies = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listCopies);
    copies.setText(cursor.getString(5));

}

}
```

Comment: see `CursorLoader` sources - `onStartLoading` in particular

Comment: add your `DBHandler` and `MyCursorAdapter` class

Comment: @OussemaAroua DBHandler is quite large. I've used DBHandler to get cursor on the UI thread and it works. DBHandler.getCursor() loads a cursor from database. I'll upload the adapter

Comment: I've used the adapter and dbhandler to load data in the UI thread successfully.

Comment: and instead of `MyCursorAdapter` just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: @pskink I need to use `MyCursorAdapter` because I need to override `bindview`(I will add other UI Elements like `checkBox` later on). If I Override `bindView` on `SimpleCursorAdaper`, Is'nt it the same as using `MyCursorAdapter`? Or is there something implemented in `SimpleCursorAdapter` that I forgot to

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `DBLoader loader` as global variable

at the `onCreateLoader`

```
loader  = new DBLoader(this);
return loader;
```

put this at the `onCreate` method instead of `onLoadFinished`

```
myAdapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this,null,0);
bookList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

put this at `onLoadFinishied`

```
this.loader=(DBLoader)loader;
adapter.changeCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: by global you mean as a class variable right? i tried it as a normal class variable and a `static` one. Neither works

Comment: there is no log for error ? try to log if cursor is empty or not

Comment: solved it ( somehow ? ). Adding a `.forceLoad()` to `getSupportLoaderManager` does the trick. (this probably will cause the loader to reload on orientation change...)

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I saw a few examples on the internet where they use 
a `getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this).forceLoad();`. That seems to work. also calling `loader.forceLoad()` in the `onCreateLoader()` works too. On further checking, I saw this : https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36925900

It seems we have to implement `forceLoad` in `onStartLoading()` as thus:

```
protected void onStartLoading() { 
if (mCursor != null) { 
    deliverResult(mCursor); 
} 
if (takeContentChanged() || mCursor == null) { 
    forceLoad(); 
} 
}
```

doing this will cease the need for a `.forceLoad()` in our Activity